# How to get a element without a special child in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Now I use jQuery to select some element.

**CODE:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="key_word" class="form-control" value="">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-bg-red">
            GO
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And I have other form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="key_word" class="form-control" value="">
        <input type="text" name="test" class="form-control" value="">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-bg-red">
            GO
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

How to just select the first form by jQuery? Namely how to get a element without a special child?

Comment: `$('form.form-horizontal').eq(0)`?

Comment: What makes the child "special"?

Comment: I guess, you mean "not having a child test element"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)**(or **[`not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/)**) and **[`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector)**

```js
$('form:not(:has(input[name="test"]))').css('background', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" action="">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="key_word" class="form-control" value="">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-bg-red">
      GO
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
<form class="form-horizontal" action="">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="key_word" class="form-control" value="">
    <input type="text" name="test" class="form-control" value="">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-bg-red">
      GO
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

---

```js
$('form').not(':has(input[name="test"])').css('background', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" action="">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="key_word" class="form-control" value="">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-bg-red">
      GO
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
<form class="form-horizontal" action="">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="key_word" class="form-control" value="">
    <input type="text" name="test" class="form-control" value="">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-bg-red">
      GO
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Note that `:has` is not CSS, it's a jQuery addition. (There's been on-and-off talk of adding it to CSS, but it's not in it [yet].)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following selector:

```
$("form:not(:has([name='test']))");
```

which will only select `form` elements which have no descendants with name `test`.

Here is the [working JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ykurmangaliyev/wmz37g2b/1/). Note that the second form is colored red, because it has no `test` item.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for a form which doesn't have input element with 'form-control' class (only difference I can see between both forms), then

```
var result = $( ".form-horizontal" ).filter( function(){

   return $( this ).find( '.form-control' ).size() == 0;

} );
```